# Open spreadsheet xml, save as Excel by default

Tags: xml, excel, http, xslt

In a web application, I am generating a spreadsheet XML using an XSL template. I want this spreadsheet XML to open in Excel by default. So, I add the below properties to the response:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment;Filename=export.xls");
Response.Charset = "";
```

This however, has 2 issues, first I get the message below:

```
The file you are trying to open, 'Response.xls', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?
```

And 2nd, when I try to save it, it tries to save as an .xml file by default. I want this to save as an Excel file by default, anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

An Excel XLS file is not the same format as an Open Spreadsheet XML file, which is why Excel moans at you when it tries to open an XLS and find it is not one. Excel can, of course, open Open Spreadsheet XML files, which it why it still opens it in Excel. But it is an XML file, and so when you save it again, it will still be an XML file. The only way to get around this issue, I think, is to do Save As, and change the format manually to .XLS.

For the first issue though, there may be something you can do. Rename the file back as Export.xml, but make sure the following processing instruction appears at the top of your XML file

```
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
```

This should hopefully make the XML file be opened in Excel, as opposed Internet Explorer.

In terms of XSLT though, to output such a processing instruction, you'll need to add this code to your XSLT stylesheet before any elements are output

```
<xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">
  <xsl:text>progid="Excel.Sheet"</xsl:text>
</xsl:processing-instruction>
```

Answer (score -1):

Late here, but if anyone comes across this issue, here's how I solved it.

If the extension isn't so important and you're using XSLT, you can do what Tim C explained for the XSLT file and add the following

```
<xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">
  <xsl:text>progid="Excel.Sheet"</xsl:text>
</xsk:processing-instruction>
```

Then in your code, you would make the extension .xml instead of .xls

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment;Filename=export.xml");
```

This will export the file with a .xml extension, but it will, by default, open up without any errors in MS Excel 2007 while keeping all of the styles that exist in the transform file.

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Closing tag should be </xsl:processing-instruction>, not xsk.